# Jupyter notebook can't connect to kernel (connection failed)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I previously haven't had any issues with jupyter notebook, but starting today my notebooks couldn't connect to the server. In my terminal I got the error message

```
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<HTTP1ServerConnection._server_request_loop() running at /Users/gregoryswart/work/nlp/nlp_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py:825> wait_for=<Future finished result=b'GET /api/co...rigin\r\n\r\n'> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /Users/gregoryswart/work/nlp/nlp_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:687]> while another task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<MultiKernelManager._async_start_kernel() running at /Users/gregoryswart/work/nlp/nlp_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py:214>> is being executed.
```

I saw the issue had something to do with the tornado package `tornado` so I tried reinstalling it and after that wasn't successful I completely uninstalled all external packages and tried a clean installation of `jupyter` but I am still having the same issue.

Based on another, similar question I also tried adding my user with

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

but I am still encountering the issue. Does anyone know how to solve this?

In my terminal I get these messages upon opening a notebook:

```
[W 13:46:23.161 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/pydeck/extension.js (127.0.0.1) 17.670000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NOTEBOOK_NAME.ipynb
[W 13:46:23.301 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js (127.0.0.1) 5.000000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/NOTEBOOK_NAME.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall --upgrade jupyter
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, unfortunately

Comment: can you give me the whole error ?

Comment: The issue seems to have resolved itself, I guess?

I had created a new virtualenv with a clean jupyter install, where I was able to connect. Here I was having some issues with `sys.executable` so I tried opening the notebook with my old venv, and I can now connect to the server.

The frustrating thing was, after reinstalling `tornado` there was no error messages in my terminal, it was just jupyter notebook telling me I can't connect. Thanks for the help, anyway!